# Update TestFlight iOS Build only for one group of external testers

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

This is sort of two related questions:

1. **Only send new build to subset of external testers**
   I have a prerelease version of an app in TestFlight which has been sent to a few hundred external testers. I'd like to send a new build (same version) of the app to "Submit For Beta App Review", and when that is approved **only** send the updated build out to a subset of external testers. Is that possible?
2. **Force update to new build for external testers**
   Eventually, I'd like to force my external testers to update to the newest version of the app and not allow them to use the previous build. Is this possible?

Comment: I do not think this is possible, when you activate *TestFlight* for a new build it automatically turns off the older one.